# Accessing a byte[] in host application from a dynamically loaded DLL

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Our project has some DLL's with GUI controls in it. We are loading the DLL's dynamically using Reflection. But the issue is the GUI controls will access a common `byte[]` in the host application.

Now I am not sure how to access this byte array. Is there any way to access the data in the host application?

Answer (score 2):

Simple - you dont. When the DLL is loaded, it exposes an interface (class) that the host uses to tell it the byte array reference. I.e. it is not the contro accessing the array, it is the application telling the control's assembly where the array is.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I still did not get what you mean.Maybe can you tell me some buzzwords with which i can get more information on this topic.I am not able to understand how to access the exposed interface(class with byte[]) from the dll.

Thanks.
SCP